# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am having this error whenever I run my Spring MVC App.  I have been trying to integrate Spring Security but have been unsuccessful at injecting my custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler and so I get the following error pertaining to the application context:

```
2017-11-07 16:05:03 ERROR ContextLoader:350 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: \
  Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': \
    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'auth'; \
      nested exception is
        org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: \
          No qualifying bean of type \
            'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
```

I have my project on GitHub: https://github.com/riveraadrian571/Staging-Management-System-Modifed-.git .  I am using an oracle database and in pom.xml file am using a jdbc driver that I have in my local repository so you may want to change that. I am also using tomcat server to run the app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of the code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

In WebSecurityConfig you have

```
@Autowired
AuthenticationSuccessHandler  auth;
```

Which is an Interface. You need to specify any specific implementation from standard:

All Known Implementing Classes:

- ForwardAuthenticationSuccessHandler,
- SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler,
- SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler

@see [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html)

Or implement your custom.

Comment: I created a class  in the same package called AuthSuccessHandler which I thought could be be injected to the WebSecurityConfig via autowire.  Is that not right or even possible?

Comment: Apart of the a bit brining to a mess name you are in the right way. Now you are ok to autowire your handler into WebSecurityConfig